# Creative asteroid names?

Tags: space-engineers

After finding out that we can spawn in Asteroids in Creative Mode by using <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>F10</kbd>, I wasn't very happy.

There is a **massive** list of really weird and obscure names for asteroids for eg. *"China Corridor"*.

Like, what on Earth is *that* meant to mean?

Is there a guide to choosing the correct asteroid to spawn in?
Is there a list of **details** *per* asteroid? (by name)

Comment: Asking why they have such weird names is off-topic, as we're not the developers, and can't answer it.  The rest of the question looks to be on-topic, though, so I'd recommend removing that aspect so answerers can focus on the parts they can answer.

Comment: @Frank So... What part should I keep?

Comment: @FinnRayment The last two lines. Anything which is subjective on the part where you just don't like how the game works or whatever is quite irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless someone spawned all of them and made a list of their details, no, there is no way of knowing what they will look like unless you spawned one before. What you could do is spawn one in and destroy it if you don't want it.

Comment: May you please give me details on how to destroy the Asteroid?

Comment: The fun way is to blow them up, or you could mine it

Comment: Well, I tend to try and create things and see how I go in Survival. Blowing it up will just cause debris to fly everywhere. Is there another way? Perhaps through console?

Comment: I don't think you can do it through the console, but you could save and reload

Comment: Ok. I will see how I go, and since this has been bumped, I will allow more time for different answers.

Comment: That's always a good idea

Answer (score -2):

I've found posts with name and images.

Here is the one I've found the more useful (because there's a scale on the images) :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/asExs.jpg

Answer (score -3):

Actually, someone did a guide, displaying each and every asteroid with its respective name ingame:
https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=330867915

Comment: Question:  is there a guide to the **massive** list?  Answer:  here's one.  You can't summarize a list.  A better criticism of this post would point out that the list doesn't really include details on most asteroids, just name and picture.